# How can we get rid of space debris?

Tags: debris, collision-avoidance

It's known that space debris can do harm to satellites. I have 2 questions:

1. How do satellites avoid them?
2. Are there any ways to get rid of it?

Comment: There is a very detailed article in Wikipedia on this topic... much more detail than you would get here in an asnswer. If you go through that Wiki article it would allow you to focus your question so Space Exploration answers can fill in the blanks.

Comment: Welcome to space stack exchange! One question per post, please. Feel free to edit one of the questions here out, and put it in a new post.  I'm voting to close because (quoting the wording on the close vote rationale) "This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."